# Salesforce extract report to FTP location

Tags: salesforce, reporting

I would like to extract a Salesforce report into a CSV file and drop it into my FTP location. I would like this as a nightly scheduled task.

Is there a straight forward way to do this in Salesforce?

Thanks.

Edit - I ended up using the dataloader to schedule a job in Windows to extract the information I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the report data to CSV either via the Analytics API or a direct to CSV URL - see [Can report data be accessed programatically?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically)

You would need to use your programming tool of choice to extract the data and send it to the FTP server as Salesforce does not support FTP transfers.

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stackexchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a straight forward way to do this in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across a webbased dataloader called AutoRABIT(http://www.autorabit.com) dataloader.
Which support nightly scheduled task and also many advanced features.

Regards,

Naveen